# Interpretar código QR-Code

Tags: php, qrcode

Boa tarde pessoal.

Estou trabalhando em um projeto que visa usar o sistema QR-Code. Em resumo, criei um site cujo há um botão que ao clicar, abre a câmera do aparelho móvel (seja celular ou tablet), e ao passar o código QR-Code impresso, o site lê e interpreta aquele código e busca os dados lidos no banco de dados. Seria possível me indicarem um artigo ou algo semelhante, onde ensina criar essa forma de interpretação?

Explicando de outra forma, o site está pronto, mas, gostaria que quando viesse com um QR-Code impresso num papel por exemplo, ao clicar no botão no site e passar sob o código, o site ler e carregar os dados.

Alguém sabe onde encontro essa informação?

Comment: https://github.com/khanamiryan/php-qrcode-detector-decoder

Comment: Eu abri o link Adir, mas, ao olhar os detalhes do documento eu percebi a falta do arquivo autoload.php. Tem certeza que seria estes os códigos?

Comment: Vê se ajuda: https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/504923-tutorial-gerarlerescanear-qrcodes-com-php-e-javascript/

Comment: o autoload eh criado pelo composer, que eh um gerenciador de pacotes para o PHP. https://getcomposer.org/